# How do I format data from front end component to a specfic format in node js?

Tags: node.js

I have the below data from a front end component

```
{
  "columns": [
    {
      "header": "Student Name",
      "colSpan": 1
    },
    {
      "header": "Sam",
      "colSpan": 1
    },
    {
      "header": "Julian",
      "colSpan": 1
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "label": "Section",
      "placeholder": "",
      "data": [
        {
          "0": "",
          "dataType": "Sam"
        },
        {
          "1": "",
          "dataType": "Julian"
        }
      ],
      "isDropDown": false
    },
    {
      "label": "FirstName",
      "placeholder": "",
      "data": [
        {
          "0": "Rogers",
          "dataType": "Sam"
        },
        {
          "1": "Blake",
          "dataType": "Julian"
        }
      ],
      "isDropDown": false
    },
    {
      "label": "City",
      "placeholder": "",
      "data": [
        {
          "0": "NY",
          "dataType": "Sam"
        },
        {
          "1": "Seattle",
          "dataType": "Julian"
        }
      ],
      "isDropDown": false
    },
    {
      "label": "Grade",
      "placeholder": "",
      "data": [
        {
          "0": "1st Grade",
          "dataType": "Sam"
        },
        {
          "1": "2nd Grade",
          "dataType": "Julian"
        }
      ],
      "isDropDown": false
    },
    {
      "label": "Section",
      "placeholder": "",
      "data": [
        {
          "0": "",
          "dataType": "Sam"
        },
        {
          "1": "",
          "dataType": "Julian"
        }
      ],
      "isDropDown": false
    }
  ]
}
```

I want this data to be modified into a different format as below object

```
[{Name:"Sam",Grade:"1stgrade",section:"",FirstName:"Rogers",City:"NY"},{Name:"Julian",Grade:"2ndgrade",section:"",FirstName:"Blake",City:"Seattle"}]
```

I tried creating a new object and add names first. Goal is to create the output shown above but am facing issues in the first step itself

```
const col=data.columns
const dat=data.data
var arr={}
console.log(col)
for(var i=0;i<col.length;i++)
{
    arr[i]={}
    arr[i].NAME=col[i].header
}
console.log(arr)
```

Am getting the desired name populated. Output is appended with index values. How do I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

As per the sample data in the question, you can loop through the data key in the object:

```js
const sampleData ={
  "columns": [
    {
      "header": "Student Name",
      "colSpan": 1
    },
    {
      "header": "Sam",
      "colSpan": 1
    },
    {
      "header": "Julian",
      "colSpan": 1
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "label": "Section",
      "placeholder": "",
      "data": [
        {
          "0": "",
          "dataType": "Sam"
        },
        {
          "1": "",
          "dataType": "Julian"
        }
      ],
      "isDropDown": false
    },
    {
      "label": "FirstName",
      "placeholder": "",
      "data": [
        {
          "0": "Rogers",
          "dataType": "Sam"
        },
        {
          "1": "Blake",
          "dataType": "Julian"
        }
      ],
      "isDropDown": false
    },
    {
      "label": "City",
      "placeholder": "",
      "data": [
        {
          "0": "NY",
          "dataType": "Sam"
        },
        {
          "1": "Seattle",
          "dataType": "Julian"
        }
      ],
      "isDropDown": false
    },
    {
      "label": "Grade",
      "placeholder": "",
      "data": [
        {
          "0": "1st Grade",
          "dataType": "Sam"
        },
        {
          "1": "2nd Grade",
          "dataType": "Julian"
        }
      ],
      "isDropDown": false
    },
    {
      "label": "Section",
      "placeholder": "",
      "data": [
        {
          "0": "",
          "dataType": "Sam"
        },
        {
          "1": "",
          "dataType": "Julian"
        }
      ],
      "isDropDown": false
    }
  ]
}

const results = sampleData.data.reduce((ini, el, index) => { 
    if (index == 0) {
       ini['Name'] = `${el.data[0]['dataType']} ${el.data[1]['dataType']}`;
    }
    ini[el.label] = el.data[0][0];
    return ini;
 }, {});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thank you apoorva. It works!But I have many such fields. In the code you are considering data.data[1]. Can we make it dynamic?

Comment: Can you add that in the question? And what do you need as a result?

Comment: Check now if it helps.

Comment: apoorva...output for the code you provided is different from the expected one can you pls help?

Comment: I will check and update the answer in a while.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works

```
var arr=[]
const col=data.columns
for(var i=0;i<col.length-1;i++)
{
const results = data.data.reduce((ini, el, index) => { 
    if (index == 0) {
       ini['NAME'] = `${el.data[i]['dataType']}`;
    }
    ini[el.label] = el.data[i][i];
    return ini;
},{});
    
    arr.push(results)
}
console.log(arr)
```